# Get One Column's Data from Db and Set it to multiple Checkboxes in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have multiple `Checkboxes` in a page and their values are being stored in `one column`. Now I want that if I get data from Db then Checkbox is checked if their value is store in that column.
**What Store Procedure and C# code I use for this?**

[image]
[image]

**Here is my code;**

```
private void SetRoles()
{
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SPD_GetAllUsersList");
    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "ABC01");
    SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
    cmd2.Connection = con;
    sda2.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    sda2.Fill(dt2);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
    bool recfound2 = dr2.Read();
    if (recfound2)
    {
        if (dt2.Columns[0].ToString() == "Add Staff".ToString())
        {
            CBAddStaff.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            CBAddStaff.Checked = false;
        }

        if (dt2.Columns[0].ToString() == "Update Staff".ToString())
        {
            CBAUpdateStaff.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            CBAUpdateStaff.Checked = false;
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: We are not here to write your code for you. You need to make your best attempt and then, if it doesn't work, show us what you did and tell us what happened. If you haven't tried anything then you haven't encountered an issue yet.

Comment: You need to provide code snippet that you tried or a minimum repro example, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As it is now, your question lacks details to help you.

Comment: Images aren't code. They can't be copied, compiled or tested. Besides, both reading data and data binding is explained in the ASP.NET docs and `Getting Started` tutorials for all stacks, and a *lot* of books, courses and tutorials. Start with a tutorial instead of trying code at random - what's the point of that datatable and adapter if they're never used?

Comment: *"did you think I did not try anythink"*. I've been answering questions on sites like this for  almost 20 years and I have seen countless instances of people who haven't tried anything. If you don't show us what you've tried then how would we know either way. It's not just about our knowing that you've tried something either. It's about our knowing exactly what you've tried and exactly what happened when you tried it, so we know exactly what problem we're helping to address. For all we know, you're 99% of the way there. We don't need to explain things you are already doing.

Comment: You should spend some time in the Help Center to learn what is expected of a question on this site. The rules are very simple and, if you follow them, you'll generally get the help you want quickly. If we have to fight to get every bit of information that should have been posted in the first place, it will take far longer to get your answer and many who might provide are likely to just give up. Help us to help you. We're here because we want to help. Don't make that difficult to achieve.

Comment: *"I thinked this is helping platform instead of teasing"*. No one is teasing you. I'm merely explaining how this site works. If you don't want us to have to explain that, you can read it for yourself in the Help Center. We're all here to help, myself included, but that doesn't mean that you can use the site contrary to the way it is intended.

Comment: My code is available in the post in soft format. You may check it right now. My question is simple not complicated. I want to use only one Store Procedure instead of many and want to use conditions on query result in c#. If any oher way or some changes in this code?

Answer (score 1):

There are many things wrong with your peace of code my friend

1. Your code for reading data from database is too long, and doesn't even make much sense. Try this:

> A little tip: read the data in a separate method.

```
private DataTable ReadRoles()
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("SPD_GetAllUsersList");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "ABC01");
    var con = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString");
    var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, con);
    var cmb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
    var ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds);
    return ds.Tables[0];
}
```

Now we store the returned `DataTable` in a variable, and search through that:

```
var Roles = ReadRoles();
CBAddStaff.Checked = false;
CBAUpdateStaff.Checked = false;
foreach (DataRow row in Roles)
{
    if (row["RoleId"].ToString() == "Add Staff") CBAddStaff.Checked = true;
    else if (row["RoleId"].ToString() == "Update Staff") CBAUpdateStaff.Checked = true;
    else continue;
}
```

Now, if you really need to use all of this in one method, I suggest you create method that does everything in the second piece of code I wrote: Call the `ReadRoles()`, uncheck both ckechboxes (so you don't need if-else , if-else), and set `Checked` of the right checkbox to `true`

Don't forget to vote and accept if you find this helpful

Comment: There are some errors in these lines;

var sda = new SqlDataAdapter( **cmd, con** );

foreach (DataRow row in **Roles** )

Comment: If you could give me the error I could help you better, but for now, try `new SqlDataAdapter()` with no parameters, and then `cmd.Connection = con;  sda.SelectCommand = cmd;`

Comment: As for the `foreach` error, I need to see the error to be able to help